# compute string length in Spark SQL DSL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, string-length

Edit: this is an old question concerning Spark 1.2

I've been trying to compute on the fly the length of a string column in a SchemaRDD for orderBy purposes. I am learning Spark SQL so my question is strictly about using the DSL or the SQL interface that Spark SQL exposes, or to know their limitations.

My first attempt has been to use the integrated relational queries, for instance

```
notes.select('note).orderBy(length('note))
```

with no luck at the compilation:

```
error: not found: value length
```

(Which makes me wonder where to find what "Expression" this DSL can actually resolve. For instance, it resolves "+" for column additions.)

Then I tried

```
sql("SELECT note, length(note) as len FROM notes")
```

This fails with

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: length
```

(Then I reread this (I'm running 1.2.0)
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#supported-hive-features
and wonder in what sense Spark SQL supports the listed hive features.)

Questions: is the length operator really supported in Expressions and/or in SQL statements? If yes, what is the syntax? (bonus: is there a specific documentation about what is resolved in Spark SQL Expressions, and what would be the syntax in general?)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `hive-site.xml` in your classpath? Usually it is in `$SPARK_HOME/conf`. This file contains Hive classpath configuration.

Comment: nope, I don't find any hive-site.xml anywhere in the spark home

Comment: Do you imply that the hive features are only available when working with Hive tables? So Spark SQL does not support these features on RDD, one has to store tables in Hive first?

Comment: I've just tested: `hive-site.xml` is useful to configure Hive but not necessary. Your SQL query works out of the box on Spark 1.2.1 in *local* mode. If you're running your query in a cluster (what  kind?) does it have Hive enabled?

Comment: hmmm... I'm in local mode, but 1.2.0. I can try 1.2.1

Comment: No luck with 1.2.1, same problem. Additional info: query and physical plans are empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in Spark Shell:

```
case class Note(id:Int,text:String)
val notes=List(Note(1,"One"),Note(2,"Two"),Note(3,"Three"))
val notesRdd=sc.parallelize(notes)
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val hc=new HiveContext(sc)
import hc.createSchemaRDD
notesRdd.registerTempTable("note")
hc.sql("select id, text, length(text) from note").foreach(println)
```

It works on by setup (out of the box spark 1.2.1 with hadoop 2.4):

```
[2,Two,3]
[1,One,3]
[3,Three,5]
```

Comment: yep, that works. So it requires to work in the hive context. Ok.Thanks!

Comment: ...and for the record, somebody showed me what I wanted about operators allowed within an expression [here (aggregates)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregates.scala) and [here (arithmetic)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/arithmetic.scala). No length operation on strings...

Comment: or you can register your own string length function as

Comment: Answer is super. There is no length operator on column in SQL Context.

Answer (score 6):

It now exists!

Your `spark.sql("SELECT note, LENGTH(note) as len FROM notes")` should work.

I'm running Spark 2.2.0, just did it and it worked.